# Google speech recognizer for Traditional Chinese text

Tags: java, android, google-speech-api, chinese-locale, google-voice-search

I want to output the speech to traditional chinese but it output to simplify chinese instead. My codes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh-TW");
```

I also tried to set EXTRA_LANGUAGE to "zh_TW", "TW" and Locale.TAIWAN but it doesn't work too.

In my Android 7.0 settings "Traditional Chinese"(繁體中文) is added in Language preferences. I able to select it in keyboard & type it.

Is this a bug of google speech recognizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, need to use
cmn-Hant-TW for EXTRA_LANGUAGE.
Google documentation is sucks.